# notification showing up instantly

Tags: android

am trying to schedule a notification with desired time and un the below code my desired time if after 10 seconds but i don't know why its showing up the notification instantly , am i doing anything wrong ? or missing anything please correct me if am wrong anywhere ,  and am using BlueStacks Emulator for testing (built version 4.4.2 Api 19)

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notification.setAutoCancel(true);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");


PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
// why its showing up instantly insted of after 10 seconds 

//alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,20,broadcast);


Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);

notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ok);
notification.setWhen(20);
notification.setTicker("you've got a meesage");
notification.setContentTitle("new message");
notification.setContentText("wanna take a ride?");

//   notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> notification showing up instantly

When you call `notificationManager.notify()` in your last line, it displays the notification immediately.

I assume that you wanted to use an `AlarmManager` to display a notification and you don't quite understand what it does. An `AlarmManager` is used schedule an `Intent` to be broadcasted. An `Intent` can be used to perform a variety of task such as starting an `Activity` or `Service`. As far as i know it is not possible to use an `Intent` to display notification.

What you should be looking at is to use `postDelayed()` method in `Handler` class. For example:

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Create your notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        // and call notificationManager.notify()
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, /*time to delay for in ms*/);
```

Edit: If you really want to use `AlarmManager` and broadcast to display a notification, you will need to extend a `BroadcastReceiver` and have it listen for your `PendingIntent` broadcast. Next, you will schedule the `PendingIntent` to be broadcasted using `AlarmManager`. When the `AlarmManager` fire off the `PendingIntent` after 10 seconds, your `BroadcastReceiver` will receive the broadcast and call `notificationManager.notify()` to display the notification. This is quite a roundabout way of displaying notification.